# Use AWS::EC2::Instance in AWS::CloudFormation::Init

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have some LaunchConfig for AS group

```
   "LaunchConfig": {
     "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",

     "Metadata" : {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
          "configSets" : {
            "InstallAndRun" : [ "Install" ]
          },

          "Install" : {

            "files" : {

              "/var/www/html/index.html" : {
                "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                "<html\n",
                "<h1>Apache HTTP Server</h1>\n",
                "</html>\n"
              ]]},
              "mode"    : "000644",
              "owner"   : "apache",
              "group"   : "apache"
              }, 
            ......
```

It's possible or what the best approach add to index.html some data, like, for example, instance-id from AWS::EC2::Instance using "files" sections?

If I add { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" } or { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, it works fine, but its from Pseudo Parameter.

```
              "/var/www/html/index.html" : {
                "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                "<html\n",
                "<h1>Apache HTTP Server</h1>\n",
                { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" },
                "</html>\n"
              ]]},
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest adding the file externally. i.e have it on S3 and pull it during EC2 launch. Mainly because you'll have the flexibility of adding as much content to it, as necessary - without the template looking messy. Then injecting any extra data to it using the sed command in the EC2 launch script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to do this directly, but you should be able to accomplish this by placing a file, and then afterwards running a command to update it:

(Disclaimer: I haven't explicitly tested this.)

```
{
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
        "configSets": {
            "InstallAndRun": [
                "Install",
                "UpdateIndexHtml"
            ]
        },
        "Install": {
            "files": {
                "/var/www/html/index.html": {
                    "content": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "<html\n",
                                "<h1>Apache HTTP Server</h1>\n",
                                "---INSTANCE_ID---\n",
                                "</html>\n"
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    "mode": "000644",
                    "owner": "apache",
                    "group": "apache"
                }
            }
        },
        "UpdateIndexHtml": {
            "commands": {
                "UpdateIndexHtml": {
                    "command": "sed -i \"s|---INSTANCE_ID---|$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)|\" /var/www/html/index.html"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```